# Existential quantification in Prolog facts

Tags: prolog, logic, existential-operator

I am doing my first steps in Prolog (swi-prolog) and cannot solve the following problem: How can I include existentially quantified rules to my facts; specifically, how can I include the sentence "Everybody is a friend of somebody" `\forall x \exists y friend(x,y)`as a fact? Every question I found so far was only about queries not facts. Thank you!

Comment: seems relevant: https://faculty.nps.edu/ncrowe/book/chap14.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the example you gave, you are actually quantifying over variables not rules. With this in mind, consider the following example:

```
friend_of(a,b).

friend(X) :-
   friend_of(X,Y).
```

The variables in the rule are universally quantified, so you can write the rule as a logic formula like so:

∀`X`∀`Y` `(friend(X)` ← `friend_of(X,Y))`

Since the variable `Y` does not occur in the head of the rule, its universal quantifier can be moved into the body of the rule as existential quantifier:

∀`X` `(friend(X)` ← ∃`Y` `friend_of(X,Y))`

Now this formula reads as: *Forall* `X` `friend(X)` *is true if there exists a* `Y` *such that* `friend_of(X,Y)` *is true*. This seems to be pretty close to what you wanted.

If you consider facts on the other hand, they are used to state that something is the case. The fact `friend_of/2` in the above example is just the short way of writing

```
friend_of(a,b) :- true.
```

However, there are no variables here, so there's nothing to quantify over.

EDIT: Concerning the case in your comments, I would note that predicates constitute relations. Relations are not neccessarily symmetric, that is the reason why I named the relation `friend_of/2`. That is, `friend_of(a,b)` does not neccessarily mean `friend_of(b,a)`. Relations are also not neccessarily reflexive. It is debatable whether the relation friend is reflexive or not. However, it certainly is a possible reading. With that in mind and the given examples in your comment, let's assume that you have some facts that describe `a`, `b` and `c` as persons, like so:

```
person(a).
person(b).
person(c).
```

Then you can describe a reflexive relation `friends/2` like so:

```
friends(a,b) :- false.   % example from your comment
friends(a,c) :- false.   % example from your comment
friends(X,X) :-          % the relation is reflexive
   person(X).            % among people
```

The rule expressing reflexivity basically states, that everybody is friends with at least him/herself. From this rule your requirement *Everybody is a friend of someone* directly follows. If you query this relation you get the desired result:

```
   ?- friends(a,X).
X = a
```

The most general query also yields results for every person, although no actual friendships between two different people are stated:

```
   ?- friends(X,Y).
X = Y = a ? ;
X = Y = b ? ;
X = Y = c
```

Note that the facts `person/1` are neccessary to restrict the answers to actual people. If you query `friends/2` with some non-person:

```
   ?- friends(cos(0),X).
no
```

If you try to define reflexivity without such a goal:

```
friend(X,X).
```

your definition will be too general:

```
   ?- friends(a,X).           % desired result
X = a
   ?- friends(cos(0),X).      % undesired result
X = cos(0)
```

And the most general query will not produce any actual people:

```
   ?- friends(X,Y).
X = Y
```

Comment: You are right I mixed up the terminology a little. I guess the goal of this exercise is to infer friendship given some facts. E.g. if I know there are only a,b and c and ~friend(a,b) and ~friend(a,c) I could infer friend(a,a) due to the mentioned rule. I do not quite get yet how that would work with your proposed solution.

Comment: @huxley: What do mean by "~friend(a,b)"? Do you mean that you have given a fact `friend(a,b)`? Or that you have explicitly stated that `a` and `b` are not friends, e.g.: `friend(a,b) :- false.`?

Comment: The second case is what I meant. So given the knowledge that a and b as well a and c are not friends, how could I infer that a and a must be friends (friend(a,a)) given "Everybody is a friend of someone" with your solution?

Comment: I think I got it now. Thanks!